# Sign apk with system certificate for stock build

Tags: android, apk, android-permissions, jarsigner

I have an apk that uses an API which requires a permission with `android:protectionLevel="signature"`
I understand that I need to add:

```
android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
```

to the `AndroidManifest.xml`, but other than that, I must sign my app with the same system key as my phone's.
I am using a Nexus 4 with stock Kitkat OS.
I tried signing with the keys found at:

```
build/target/product/security/
```

But it appears that this is not the key used for this ROM (unless I am doing something wrong)
Is there any way I can install the apk without a "remount"/"push to system/app" solutions ?

Comment: Wouldn't the stock ROMs for Kitkat be signed with Google's release keys? I wouldn't expect the keys used to sign the rom generated in a release build to be distributed with the source tree... I'm guessing you need key used to sign your roms so that your app will be able to run as system?

Comment: That would be my guess too, but I couldn't find an unequivocal answer to this in any of the forums